# Error sending emails to an external server hmailserver?

Tags: hmail-server

I encountered a strange oddity, when I try to send messages to an external mail server, I receive this email

> Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients.
>
> Sent: Sun, 4 Apr 2021 16:04:00 +0300 Subject: ping
>
> The following recipient(s) could not be reached:
>
> xxxxxx@yandex.ru Error Type: SMTP Connection to recipients server
> failed. Error: Could not connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port 25 since
> this would mean connecting to myself.
>
> Tried 5 time(s)
>
> hMailServer

I run the diagnostic says that everything is OK, except that the folder for the backup is not specified.
I checked the host file - there is nothing suspicious there, I do not ask you to give a 100% answer, hint where to look next? I don't even understand how to diagnose this problem, and I can't really find anything in google